# gob encoding is crashing

Tags: go

I wanted to develop a `type data struct` for the implementation of storage on disk. I ran into a problem while encoding the data object to bytes. For the encoding I wanted to use the `encoding/gob` package.

```
package data

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "io"
)
func NewKey(key string) Data {
    ret := Data{MsgType: "key", Value: key}
    return ret
}

func NewData(d string) Data {
    ret := Data{MsgType: "data", Value: d}
    return ret
}

type Data struct {
    MsgType string
    Value   string
}

func (dat Data) Encode () io.Writer {
    var ret io.Writer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(ret)
    _ = enc.Encode(dat)
    // if err != nil {
    //  panic(err)
    // }
    return ret
}
```

This is the code of the data package. My goal is to convert the `Data` type to a byte slice, so that I can store it with diskv.
My main code looks like this:
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "pkg"
)

func main() {
    testData := data.Data{MsgType:"string", Value:"1"}
    ret := testData.Encode()
    // fmt.Println(ret)
    fmt.Sprintf("%T", ret)
}
```

But when I run the code with `go run` I get the following output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x18 pc=0x4a15b4]

goroutine 1 [running]:
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).writeMessage(0xc0000440a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0000440d8)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:82 +0x134
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).sendActualType(0xc0000440a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000037600, 0xc0000375c0, 0x506800, 0x4d2580, 0x38)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:107 +0x223
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).sendType(0xc0000440a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000037600, 0x506800, 0x4d2580, 0xc000067de0)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:169 +0xda
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).sendTypeDescriptor(0xc0000440a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000037600, 0xc0000375c0)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:191 +0xd9
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).EncodeValue(0xc0000440a0, 0x4d2580, 0xc000004c00, 0x99, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:244 +0x2f3
encoding/gob.(*Encoder).Encode(0xc0000440a0, 0x4d2580, 0xc000004c00, 0xc000004c00, 0x0)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/encoding/gob/encoder.go:176 +0xad
pkg.Data.Encode(0x4e66e9, 0x6, 0x4e614a, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    C:/Users/eliap/OneDrive/Dokumente/Programming/Go/src/pkg/data.go:25 +0xa2
main.main()
    C:/Users/eliap/OneDrive/Dokumente/Programming/Go/src/test.go:10 +0x56
exit status 2
[Finished in 1.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['go', 'run', 'C:\\Users\\eliap\\OneDrive\\Dokumente\\Programming\\Go\\src\\test.go']]
[dir: C:\Users\eliap\OneDrive\Dokumente\Programming\Go\src]
[path: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files\Python37\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Typora\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\micro-1.4.1;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Midnight Commander;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\eliap\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\eliap\go\bin]
```

I'm using `go version go1.12 windows/amd64`, Windows 10 and Sublime Text 3 (If it matters)
If you have a better solution/implementation for the `Encode` method it would be even nicer.

Comment: Don't ignore errors!

Comment: You're way of handling `io.Writer` is very unusual. For one thing, printing an `io.Writer`, as you do, is meaningless. The normal way would be to pass in an existing `io.Writer` to your `Encode()` method.

Comment: Please see the examples in [the doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/). The "basic" example uses `*bytes.Buffer` (which is also `io.Writer`) so it maps almost 1-to-1 to your case.

Answer (score 4):

In

```golang
func (dat Data) Encode () io.Writer {
    var ret io.Writer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(ret)
```

you

1. Declare a variable `ret` of type `io.Writer`
2. Do not initialize it, so it has the zero-value for its type, `nil`.
3. You pass that `nil` to `gob.NewEncoder` which supposedly writes that value into its internal state.
4. As soon as you try to encode something using that encoder, and it decides it's time to actually write something to the provided `io.Writer`, it fails with that "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to write to a nil `io.Writer`:

```
var ret io.Writer
enc := gob.NewEncoder(ret)
```

`ret` is nil. So it's going to panic (as it does) when trying to write to it.

The normal way to write an `Encode()` method, would be to take an `io.Writer` as an argument:

```
func (dat Data) Encode(w io.Writer) error {
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(ret)
    return enc.Encode(dat)
}
```

Then you would call this method with an existing `io.Writer` (which may be a file, or a network socket, or whatever):

```
file, err := os.Create("somefile")
...
if err := dat.Encode(file); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to encode: %s\n", err)
}
```